# Call list.phtml within a widget

Tags: blocks, frontend

I constructed a widget where you can input product sku's and then get a small preview.

Since more and more Elements are required, I was thinking of using the `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`to show within the widget. That would be much easier then calling attribute by attribute again an designing everything allover.

So I have built an array like this:

```
$_products = array($product_1,$product_2,$product_3,$product_4);
$_products =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $_products))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addUrlRewrite();
```

Now I want to output this within a list.phtml file. Everything described so far happens in the widgets phtml file.

Is there a way to use list.phtml now? 
I tried with:

```
   <?php echo $_product->getChildHtml('prices'); ?>
```

Bu I guess I am still missing this block within the widget.

How do I load list.phtml into a new block which is working within the widgets?

EDIT: I tried this too

```
<?php echo $_product->getPriceHtml(); ?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You can extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract to use list.phtml file

Comment: Hi Mufaddal, this sounds intresting. Could you explain a bit more? Or give a url hint?

Comment: http://irnux.com/blog/article/listing-a-custom-product-collection-on-your-modules-front-end, may be this link will useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$product_block =` `new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product;`

`echo $product_block->getPriceHtml($product);` // `$product` is product object

Comment: I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreLabel() on a non-object in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml on line 53`